# Angular 10 build showing empty warning

Tags: angular, build

I've upgraded from v9.1 to v10 and when building app I'm getting two empty rows with  **WARNING in**
Is this the normal behaviour?

```
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...

chunk {0} runtime-es2015.409e6590615fb48d139f.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime-es5.409e6590615fb48d139f.js (runtime) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.a0fa45e0fa52702b64f0.js (polyfills) 36.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5.2dcde1efe3c1bf4aaa25.js (polyfills-es5) 129 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es2015.255de6c523400ad87d78.js (main) 956 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es5.255de6c523400ad87d78.js (main) 1.07 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.24597f51e944b8a89a40.css (styles) 66.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-07-11T09:05:50.932Z - Hash: 193acc530d962b76400f - Time: 104720ms

WARNING in

WARNING in
```

Comment: Good luck, web-pack errors are terrible.

Comment: With --verbose I'm getting several rows like: WARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping unused variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have raised this **[issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18231)** on the Angular CLI Team 3 days ago and that they said the patch version for this fix will be published later this week.

Let's just tune in on their updates.

---

**UPDATE FIX :**

They have now released the new patch version for this fix. You'll just need to update your packages with their latest versions:

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.4",
"@angular/cli": "^10.0.4",
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Will wait for their patch.  It's Sencond time I'm having issues after these updates

Comment: @dahas Still ongoing based on the thread link. Will update hereafter once all is well and they release a new patch fix.

Comment: @dahas Hi this is now fixed. Have updated my answer :)

Comment: Cool. Ive updated to the latest version and empty warnings are no longer showing. Thanks for the update

Comment: Hi @dahas, no problem :) Hope you can mark my answer as the accepted one? that would mean a lot! Thank you :)